# Implementing a per-model table modification time in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a Django application which edits a database table, which another application polls and uses to update a downstream system.  In order to minimize processing when the database has not been altered in between polls, I would like to use a global modification time for a model, which is updated every time a row is created/deleted/modified.  How can I do this within the Django ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not give you access, nor does it maintain, a "last modified" date on a table (model). You need to implement this by yourself, but this isn't complicated.

The easiest way would be to catch the necessary signals in your model by implementing the [`post_save()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) and [`post_delete()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-delete) model signals (hooks, basically), and maintaining a static date field which represents the "last modified" date you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks -- could you possibly expand on the concept of a "static field": is this a separate Model?

Comment: Well, you could do a separate model, but that's unnecessary. I would stick it in the models `Meta` class.